# Laravel - Handle pages with wildcard route

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-5.1

In my application I need to set a route that respond to any pages.

I have put in my `routes.php` file:

```
// Handle all the pages
Route::get('{slug?}', 'Frontend\PageController@show');
```

and it works, the problem is that now I need an admin section so in my `routes.php` I added before the previous route:

```
Route::group( [ 'prefix' => 'admin', 'middleware' => config('admin.filter.auth') ], function(){
    // other routes
}  );
```

The problem is that the url `site.com/admin` has been catch by the wildcard so I'm not able to visit that url.

This is the full routes file:

```
//admin routes
Route::group( [ 'prefix' => 'admin', 'middleware' => config('admin.filter.auth') ], function(){

    Route::get('upload-file', 'Backend\UploadController@index');
    Route::post('upload-file', 'Backend\UploadController@uploadFile');
    Route::get('load-contacts', 'Backend\UploadController@loadContacts');

}  );

// Handle all the pages
Route::get('{slug?}', 'Frontend\PageController@show');
```

How should I manage this?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily achieve that by providing a regular expression that should be used to match your **slug** parameter:

```
Route::get('{slug?}', 'Frontend\PageController@show')->where('slug', '.*');
```

The reason the **/admin** path is caught by the catch-all route is that **you don't have a route defined for /admin URL**. The only URLs that will be handled separately are

```
GET  /admin/upload-file
POST /admin/upload-file
GET  /admin/load-contacts
```

Comment: I have tried but it doesn't work. Even with that code, the `admin`is catch by `PageController`

Comment: haha, sorry, I didn't notice the other routes, I'll update the answer in a moment